# Hadith about insane man or similar

Tags: quran, hadith, sharia, sunnah

I want to know if there are hadiths that speak about insane man or similar than that then muslims should praise ALLAH because they are not like them or should seek help from ALLAH from them?

Answer (score 1):

What you may mean is a rather more general hadith about afflicted people

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “Whoever sees an afflicted person then says: ‘All praise is due to Allah who saved me from that which He has afflicted you with, and blessed me greatly over many of those whom He has created, (Al-ḥamdulillāhi alladhī `āfānī mimmabtalāka bihī wa faḍḍalanī` alā kathīrin mimman khalaqa tafḍīla)’ he shall not be struck by that affliction.”

This hadith was compiled by the imams at-Tirmidhi and ibn Majah.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not discussed in those terms.

Insanity or what would now be termed mental illness, is not considered a separate and distinct category in Islamic law. It's discussed as a cause of legal disability in such broad areas as taxation, marriage, divorce, contracts and religious obligations.

This, as all Islamic law, is derived from the Qu'ran, Hadith and Sunnah. One appropriate Hadith here is:

> Ali Ibn Ali Talib reported: The Messenger of Allah (pbuh) said "the pen is lifted from three people: The sleeper before he awakens, the child before he reaches puberty and the insane person before he regains his sanity.

From *Sunan al-Tirmidhi* and has been recorded as *sahih* (authentic) by Al-Albani.